# Automapper - Value Resolver with generics problem

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using Automapper with our asp net core application. For the mappings from type `A` -> `B` and `A` -> `C`, I need an external service to inject some additional data. Therefore I have written a `ValueResolver<T>`, where `T` is either `B` or `C`. As C# doesn't have `OR` operator for types, I use a generic `T` here.

For clarity, my value resolver looks like this:

```
public class MyValueResolver<T>: IValueResolver<A, T, string>
{
    private readonly IMyService _service;

    public MyValueResolver(IMyService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public string Resolve(A source, T destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // do something using only source and _service.
        return ...;
    }        
}
```

Now, in my startup I register automapper like this `services.AddAutoMapper();`. Therefore, when I use it anywhere in my application, I just have to inject `IMapper` in the constructor and it will resolve `MyValueResolver` with `IMyService` dependency automatically.

The problem arises in tests when I don't use DI and I need both `MyValueResolver<B>` and `MyValueResolver<C>`. I tried the following:

```
        var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
            cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(MyValueResolver =>
                new MyValueResolver<B>(service));
            cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(MyValueResolver =>
                new MyValueResolver<C>(service));
        });
        var mapper = new Mapper(mappingConfig);
```

But this doesn't work, as it sees tries to use the latter statement for both cases and fails with an error that it cannot cast `MyValueResolver<C>` to `MyValueResolver<B>`. But the method doesn't accept types with generics defined (I assume it is a C# limitation?) like this `cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(MyValueResolver<C> => new MyValueResolver<C>(service));`

Is there any workaround for this, or maybe a different pattern I could use?

Comment: I think you misunderstood how ConstructServicesUsing works. See [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/search?q=ConstructServicesUsing&unscoped_q=ConstructServicesUsing).

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! Feel free to post it as an answer and I will accept it :) @LucianBargaoanu

Comment: Silly me, I was expecting it to match types like in pattern matching in Scala.

Comment: I'm afraid it's .Net all the way down :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `ConstructServicesUsing` in a completely wrong way.

It takes a function , where Type - is a type of a `ValueResolver` I want to resolve and `Object` is the resolved instance. You should return `null` for the types you don't want to resolve.

So it looks along the lines:

```
cfg => cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type => type == typeof(MyValueResolver<B>) ? new MyValueResolver<B>(service) : null));
```

Credit goes to @LucianBargaoanu for this answer.